# MySQL - "exact match" against a value

Tags: mysql, match-against

I'm scratching my head on something and after a day of searching over the internet I've decided to ask you the question.

I got a table TAG with 2 fields tag_id and tag and I'm trying to match exactly the records of TAG against a particular string but I cannot make the match exactly, only partially. 
For instance I have 2 records in TAG:

```
tag = world
tag = world news
```

and I'm firing the following query:

```
Select tag,tag_id from TAG where match (tag) against ('Hello world')
```

And I would like only the taG "world" to be selected but both records are popping.

If I was firing

```
Select tag,tag_id from TAG where match (tag) against ('Hello world news')
```

I would like both records to pop.

Is there any way of achieving this?
Thank you in advance :)

Comment: Why are you using the fulltext search? Also note, that the value of `against` is the search string/query, not the source text to search in. So it looks like you are doing the search in the wrong order. What are you trying to do?

Comment: I want to get all records in a particular table contained in a variable sentence.
For instance I have the following records in my table:
 - world
 - world news
 - test

And I want to write a query which will browse all records of that table and will return the one which are contained against a particular sentence. For instance if I'm comparing with "Hello world", I would like to only get the record "world" from my table

Answer (score 1):

To search anything in tag column that contains abc

```
Select tag,tag_id from TAG where tag like '%abc%'
```

To search in tag column that contains abc only i.e. only equals abc

```
 Select tag,tag_id from TAG where tag = 'abc'
```

Check the following link to compare strings
https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_like.asp

Comment: Sorry but it's not doing what I'm looking for, I will try to be more explicit by commenting my question. Thanks for your time :)

Answer (score 1):

I think I actually found a way with LOCATE:

```
SELECT tag, LOCATE(tag, 'world news') from TAG where LOCATE(tag, 'world news') > 0
```

What do you think ?